# Aggregating field on lines where they overlap in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, aggregate-points

I have a network of lines representing a pedestrian footpath network. Each line intersects and follows another to an endpoint. Each line has a number representing population.

Is there an aggregate tool in QGIS that breaks the lines where they overlap and aggregate the population along that section, adding on each number at each intersection? For instance two lines with 12 and 15 meet, they follow a new segment with 27 until a line with 24 meets, the next section having 51.

I have this working with a SQL stored procedure but it is a bit cumbersome.